# How to disable the search for modules outside a pyinstaller binary?

Tags: import, binary, hook, exe, pyinstaller

When i create a binary with pyinstaller --one-flag, everything work's fine on the computer, where the binary is created. Even if i do not define any imports with the --hidden-import flag. I think the reason is, when pyinstaller cannot find the module within the binary, it searches it outside the binary. But how can i test if a import is missing? 
Is there a way to disable this behavior, to find possible missing hidden import's?